# SQL Calculation Negatives to 0

Tags: sql

I have a query I am working on for some inventory quantities, but I am running into an issue with my `CASE` to turn anything negative to `0`.

I am getting quantities based on calculation, so i assume i have to have some type of `CASE` for it as well????

I have several items that have negatives, but I cannot figure out how to `CASE` or `MAX` on this one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a sample of the query:

```
SELECT 
Item AS 'Item No.',
(
 (SELECT CASE WHEN t0.OnHand > 0 THEN t0.OnHand ELSE 0 END 
  FROM TABLE 
  WHERE ItemCode = T0.[ItemCode] AND WhsCode like 'wh') +

 (SELECT CASE WHEN OnHand > 0 THEN OnHand ELSE 0 END 
  FROM TABLEX 
  WHERE ItemCode = T0.[ItemCode] AND WhsCode like 'INT') +

 (SELECT CASE WHEN OnOrder > 0 THEN OnOrder ELSE 0 END 
  FROM TABLEX 
  WHERE ItemCode = T0.[ItemCode] AND WhsCode like 'WH') +

 (SELECT CASE WHEN OnOrder > 0 THEN OnOrder ELSE 0 END 
  FROM TABLEX 
  WHERE ItemCode = T0.[ItemCode] AND WhsCode like 'INT') -

 (SELECT CASE WHEN IsCommited > 0 THEN IsCommited ELSE 0 END 
  FROM TABLEX 
  WHERE ItemCode = T0.[ItemCode] AND WhsCode like 'WH')
) AS 'Available Qty'

FROM  DBTABLE T0
```

Comment: I see your query makes heavy use of subqueries within the topmost `SELECT` statement. I think you should rewrite your query to use a JOIN instead (e.g. `FROM dbTable LEFT OUTER JOIN tablex ON dbTable.ItemCode = tablex.ItemCode`): this should make the query run significantly faster and be easier to reason about your `CASE WHEN` expressions too.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what your issue is.  Are you getting an error?  If so, what is it?  Are you getting incorrect results?  If so, please show sample data.

Comment: What database and is the the table in the first sub query meant to be the same as in the other sub queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` statements should be used as individual columns. In other words, you don't need to repeat the word `SELECT`.

You should follow this format...

```
SELECT  Item AS 'Item No.', 
CASE WHEN OnOrder > 0 THEN OnOrder ELSE 0 END AS 'xyz', 
CASE WHEN IsCommited > 0 THEN IsCommited ELSE 0 END AS 'zyx'
FROM TableX
```

Alternatively, if you need to use multiple `SELECT` statements, (for example if you need to select data from multiple tables) you should either `JOIN` them or use a `CTE`